# php multilevel array sort by su-sub-sub array value

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp

I have a multilevel array as below

```
array( 
    (int)0=>array(
              'User' => array(
        'PostType' => array(
            'PHP' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'type_title' => 'Core Questions',
                'type_description' => 'none',
                'type_sort_order' => '7'
                'Post'=>array(
                    ......
                    ),
            ),
            'ASP' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'type_title' => 'Core Questions',
                'type_description' => 'none',
                'type_sort_order' => '1'
                'Post'=>array(
                    ......
                    ),
            ),
        ),
)));
```

I have fetched a user with its post categorized by `postType`
`postType` has type_sort_order field
I want to sort sub array `PostType` by `type_sort_order` field
so that `ASP` come before `PHP`
I tried usort as below

```
usort($arr,function(){
                return  ($a[0]['User']['PostType']['post_sort_order'] < $b[0]['User']['PostType']['post_sort_order'])?1:-1;
            });
```

and also many other sort but not getting correct result

Comment: You need to set the array as $a[0] and sort on that if you want correct results. Then you can just minus value b from value a and it should sort it no problem. If it doesn't sort in the right order try minusing value a from value b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_multisort` will work. Solution as follows:

```
$list = //Your array

$sortOrders = array();
foreach ($list[0]['User']['PostType'] as $postType) {
    $sortOrders[] = $postType['type_sort_order'];
}

array_multisort($sortOrders, $list[0]['User']['PostType']);
```

This will grab all the sort orders in an array ordered the same as your starting array. Using `array_multisort` on both arrays will sort the first array, and also apply that new order to the second array, giving you the result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Loop though PostType and take all `type_sort_order` and place in a seperate array. then use that array as an argument for array_multi_sort

it seems you are just trying to sort the sub array `PostType` so just pass that array